# Fuzzing Polkadot produces Invalid Signature after chaos is injected

Tags: polkadot-js, extrinsic, rpc, testing

I'm using Polkadot version 0.9.37-08b1c09ca46, across 4 Nodes - Alice, Bob, Charlie, Dave, in a local testnet environment. I have a period of network chaos applied, and then moments of stabilized 'happy' network conditions. I came across this logging and wondered if this is expected behaviour or not:

```
[service_workload]             [I] 2023-02-02 19:20:58        RPC-CORE: submitExtrinsic(extrinsic: Extrinsic): Hash:: 1010: Invalid Transaction: Transaction has a bad signature
[service_polkadot_dave]        [I] 2023-02-02 19:20:58 ✨ Imported #38 (0x98cb…fa88)
[service_workload]             [I] RpcError: 1010: Invalid Transaction: Transaction has a bad signature
[service_workload]             [I] at checkError (/node_modules/@polkadot/rpc-provider/cjs/coder/index.js:30:11)
[service_workload]             [I] at RpcCoder.decodeResponse (/node_modules/@polkadot/rpc-provider/cjs/coder/index.js:45:5)
[service_workload]             [I] at WsProvider.value (/node_modules/@polkadot/rpc-provider/cjs/ws/index.js:247:90)
[service_workload]             [I] at W3CWebSocket.value [as onmessage] (/node_modules/@polkadot/rpc-provider/cjs/ws/index.js:230:153)
[service_workload]             [I] at W3CWebSocket._dispatchEvent [as dispatchEvent] (/node_modules/yaeti/lib/EventTarget.js:107:17)
[service_workload]             [I] at W3CWebSocket.onMessage (/node_modules/websocket/lib/W3CWebSocket.js:234:14)
[service_workload]             [I] at WebSocketConnection.<anonymous> (/node_modules/websocket/lib/W3CWebSocket.js:205:19)
[service_workload]             [I] at WebSocketConnection.emit (node:events:513:28)
[service_workload]             [I] at WebSocketConnection.processFrame (/node_modules/websocket/lib/WebSocketConnection.js:554:26)
[service_workload]             [I] at /node_modules/websocket/lib/WebSocketConnection.js:323:40
```

The workload script is simply looping, signing and sending DOT to each account. During the network chaos I'm partitioning and causing delays across the network, however during the time this workload attempts to send, no interference is present. Would be interested in your thoughts...

Comment: Hi David, the "Hash:: 1010: Invalid Transaction: Transaction has a bad signature" error is just telling us that at least one of the expected inputs for the signature generation is wrong. I think more context and information is needed to get to the root of the error. How long are these delays? which node is broadcasting the extrinsic? which one is including it in the block? do you get any error in the "happy" scenario?